# Why Docker images from Red Hat Container Catalog are not documented?

Tags: docker, openshift, redhat

I am using keycloak image (jboss/keycloak) from DockerHub, for development environment, but I'am planning to go to Production with Red Hat SSO image from Red Hat Container Catalog (RHCC), for OpenShift.

DockerHub's keycloak image is well documented (environment variables to configure Database, initial user, volume configuration...), but RHCC's isn't.

Maybe I am missing something related to RH Docker Images...

Do you have experience with images from RHCC? Are these images though only for extension?

Comment: What platform do you use for your dev env ? Pure docker or OKD(OpenShift origin) ? OpenShift is not using the docker image directly like docker, usually the image is configured through Template parameters. Refer [3.1. Using the RH-SSO for OpenShift Image Streams and Application Templates](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_middleware_for_openshift/3/html-single/red_hat_single_sign-on_for_openshift/#using_the_rh_sso_for_openshift_image_streams_and_application_templates)

Comment: Thanks Daein, I will be using Openshift in Production environment. A big cluster. Where can in find templates for RH SSO? There is a Container Catalog by Red Hat. Is there a template Catalog or something similar? Why do you think container images in Container Catalog are not documented? I can't believe it...

Comment: Have you looked at the 'Tech Details' tab ([link](https://access.redhat.com/containers/?tab=tech-details&platform=openshift#/registry.access.redhat.com/redhat-sso-7/sso73-openshift)) where you can see the env. variables? The 'Get Latest Image' tab offers pull commands for various platforms, incl. OpenShift. Comprehensive docs are at [Red Hat Single Sign-On for OpenShift](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.3/html-single/red_hat_single_sign-on_for_openshift/).

Comment: Thanks Robert, but tech details tab only show ENV variables. Nothing about its purpose. I read the documentation outside Container Catalog Website, and I'm glad to see that there is documentation :). However, I can't find the templates for SSO, or Process Automation Manager (another product that I need to install on Openshift). Where are templates? Is there something similar to Container Catalog? Template Catalog maybe?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no 'Template Catalog', but you can get templates for these images on GitHub in official Red Hat repos. Templates for RH SSO: [redhat-sso-7-openshift-image/templates/](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/redhat-sso-7-openshift-image/tree/sso72-dev/templates). Templates for Process Automation Manager are at [rhpam-7-openshift-image/templates/docs/](https://github.com/jboss-container-images/rhpam-7-openshift-image/tree/master/templates/docs). The [docs for Process Automation Manager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/).